# Latex Warning After Update Miktex: Font shape `T1/lmr/m/scit' undefined (Font) using `T1/lmr/m/scsl' instead

Tags: miktex, warnings

I use `\textit` to italic words. Latex give me this warning.

> `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'T1/lmr/m/scit' undefined (Font) using 'T1/lmr/m/scsl' instead on input`

After I change `\textit` to `\textsl`. The warning is gone. The weird thing is, this warning doesn't occur before I reinstall miktex. Before I use `MikTeX 2.9`, now I use `MikTeX 4.0`.
But the results just fine, K italic the words.

The only problem is the warning.

Comment: Always show a full but minimal example so others can know what you're doing. I can only guess: you're attempting to use italics in a small caps context. A lot of fonts do not provide italics small caps and thus it attempts to use something else hence the message. Where exactly do you get thst you're now using miktex 4?

Answer (score 6):

In older LaTeX versions mixing small caps (`\scshape`, `\textsc`) and italic (`\itshape`, `\textit`) didn't really worked. The commands cancelled each other out, you only got the one or the other:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
{\scshape\itshape abc} {\itshape\scshape abc}
\end{document}
```

gives e.g. in texlive 2018

[image]

In newer LaTeX the font handling has been improved here. Now LaTeX tries to combine the two shapes. But lmodern has no small caps + italic shape, so LaTeX falls back to small caps + slanted:

[image]

And that is what the message is telling you: that instead of `scit` (small caps and italic) it will use `scsl` (small caps and slanted). If this fine for you you can safely ignore the message.